# How to know django tastypie is_valid is able to guarantee valid data?

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a user table stores unique user id. I overwrite is_valid function to validate register user id before save it in user table.

For example, there are browser 2 sessions trying to register same user id, at same time.

Both sessions is_valid return TRUE and commit save, which will result invalid data store in database.

Is this possible? If possible, how to avoid it?

I know django has transaction decorator. How to use it here, if applicable?

```
class UserValidation(Validation):
  '''To validate unique user name'''
  def is_valid(self, bundle, request=None):
    error = {}
    return error



class UserResource(ModelResource):

  class Meta(object):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    validation = UserValidation()
```

Comment: If you are talking about the primary key, then the database will make sure its not duplicated. If its your own value, set `unique=True` and let the database take care of it.

Comment: It's not primary key. For user id, unique=True should work fine. But, how about integer. I have a field storing values. For newly created objects, its value could not be conflict with existing object's value. For example, table with 1 row of 1st column value = 0. For newly added row, if user enters value between 0 to 10 will be invalid. I can implement is_valid to validate it. My concern is 2 sessions to create 2nd row at same time. What should I do?